# Passing data from an Asp.Net view into a React Component

Tags: reactjs, components, asp.net-core-2.0

I have the following component:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return ( <div>  
            <label>{this.props.myData.Count()}</label>
        </div>
    );
}
```

The idea being that the control displays a count of the data being passed in; here's what's currently in the Asp.Net View:

```
<div>
    <MyComponent myData={@Model.MyData} />            
</div>
```

I can see in the inspector that a value of myData has been passed to MyComponent, I also know that there is data inside of the MyData collection, but it isn't displaying anything.

I've also tried this:

```
@Html.React("MyComponent", new { myData = Model.MyData });

<div id="content">
    <MyComponent />
</div>
```

But that doesn't render at all.

I can get the control to render by using the following format:

```
<div id="content">
</div>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/js/component.jsx")"></script>
```

But this doesn't allow me to pass data in.

Being quite new to React, I assume that I need to somehow tell the component to expect an object, or something similar.  Could someone point me in the right direction, please?

Comment: do you have an existing asp application that you're trying to sprinkle some react into?

Comment: Yes - sorry, I should have made that clear.  This isn't a new application, it's an existing Asp.Net Core 2 application, and I'm trying to use React for a specific feature.

Comment: Hi User, did you end up connecting the dots of react and .net?

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I stumbled on this while researching the same problem. I had some luck passing my data over as a global javascript variable from the vbhtml/cshtml file.

My abridged vbhtml:

```
@Using (Html.BeginForm())
    @<div id="createdropdown” ></div>
    @<script src="~/scripts/bundle.js"></script>
    @<script>
        var gTypes = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
     </script>
End Using
```

My data converted to a json array (note that I structured the data to be in the format accepted by the react-select component's options):

> "[{ value: 'chocolate', label:'Chocolate' },{ value:
>   'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },{ value: 'vanilla', label:
>   'Vanilla' }]"

my jsx:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Select from 'react-select'

class CreateForm extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return (<Select options={this.props.types} placeholder="Type" />);
       }
}

ReactDOM.render(<CreateForm types={gTypes} / >, document.getElementById('createdropdown'));
```

Hope that helps :)